# how to compare two timestamp fields without seconds in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Expected : I want to comapre these two dates without seconds.
Eg

1. '2011-12-30 09:55:56', '2011-12-30 08:55:55' comparison of these two should return TRUE.
2. '2011-12-30 09:55:56', '2011-12-30 08:54:55' comparison of these two should return FALSE.

Answer (score 7):

Use `date_trunc()` and "round" the values to minutes:

```
date_trunc('minute', timestamp '2011-12-30 08:55:56') = date_trunc('minute', timestamp '2011-12-30 08:55:55')
```